# symmetric pair in sql

Tags: mysql, sql, join, select

Given the tables student, mathematics_marks, science_marks

student

```
student_id (Primary Key) | smallint

student_name             | varchar(30)
```

mathematics_marks

```
student_id (Primary Key) | smallint

score                      | float (5,2)
```

science_marks

```
student_id (Primary Key) | smallint

score                       | float (5,2)
```

A student is called as being a part of a symmetric pair if the marks obtained by that student in science is equal to the marks obtained by some other student in mathematics and the marks obtained in mathematics are the same as marks obtained by the other student in science.

Write a SQL query to print the name of the students who are a part of the symmetric pair. Order the output in order of student name.

```
with cte as (
  select m.student_id, m.score as math_score, s.score as science_score 
  from mathematics_marks m inner join science_marks s
  on s.student_id = m.student_id 
)
select s1.student_name
from cte c1 inner join cte c2 
on c2.student_id > c1.student_id and c2.math_score = c1.science_score and c1.math_score = c2.science_score
inner join student s1 on s1.student_id = c1.student_id and s1.student_id = c2.student_id
```

need to get the pair in two different rows?

EDITED:
 answer to this

```
with cte as (
  select m.student_id, m.score as math_score, s.score as science_score 
  from mathematics_marks m inner join science_marks s
  on s.student_id = m.student_id 
),
T as (select c1.student_id, c1.math_score, c1.science_score, s.student_name as name 
from cte c1 inner join student s 
on c1.student_id = s.student_id )

select t1.name from T t1 inner join T t2 
on t1.math_score = t2.science_score and
t1.science_score = t2.math_score
order by t1.name
```

Comment: You just wouldn't have separate tables for maths and science. And float is inappropriate in this instance.That should be DECIMAL.

Comment: @Strawberry I have joined those two tables first

Comment: That was your first mistake then. That would be a UNION.

Comment: oh ok will check that too but join worked for me, thank you for the help

Comment: Your specification "A student ..." does not make sense. (Although our guess at what you are trying to say would likely be correct.) Also "get the pair in two different rows" is unclear.  Use enough words, sentences & references to parts of examples to clearly & fully say what you mean. When giving a business relation(ship)/association or table (base or query result), say what a row in it states about the business situation in terms of its column values. We cannot reason, communicate or search unless we make the effort to (re-re-re-)write clearly. See [ask] & the voting arrow mouseover texts.

Comment: I disagree with philipxy. Don't use words. Just provide a clear, concise example - a sample data set, and a desired result, as text, not pictures.

Comment: Please don't insert EDITs/UPDATEs, just make your post the best presentation as of right now. Adding to something unclear doesn't make it clear.

Comment: @Strawberry I didn't say *not* to give an example.

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code; example input (as initialization code) with desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. For errors that includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) For SQL that includes DBMS & DDL, which includes constraints & indexes & tabular initialization. Please [use text, not images/links, for text--including tables & ERDs](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097).

Comment: sorry @philipxy I new to this forum and sql both. I will try to be clear from next time. thank you for your suggestions.

Comment: Try to be clear from *this* time.

Answer (score 0):

A properly designed schema would have a single table for student, subject, and mark. The first step then is to emulate that table, which could be as follows:

```
SELECT student_id 
     , 'mathematics' subject
     , score 
  FROM mathematics_marks                    
 UNION  
SELECT student_id 
     , 'science' 
     , score     
  FROM science_marks
```

For further help, see: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: They (seem to) want (s1) rows where exists s2, m, s [m(s1,m) & s(s1,s) & m(s2,s) & s(s2,m) & s1<>s2]. No need to union because desired students must appear in both tables, not either. If you tag rows then union, you then still have to join with restrictions that recreate restrictions of the original tables & all desired students appear in each of 2 columns of the (symmetric) restriction of the join. So there's no benefit to union.

Answer (score 0):

It's always easy to answer if the post is accompanied by sample data and expected output . Are you looking for somthing like this

```
Select student.student_id
       ,maths.score maths_socer
       ,sci.score science_score
from 
(
  Select 1 student_id union all
  Select 2 union all
  Select 3
) student
Join 
 (
  Select 1 student_id, 20 score union all
  Select 2, 30 union all
  Select 3, 40
 ) maths
on maths.student_id=student.student_id
Join
(
Select 1 student_id , 30 score union all     
Select 2,20 union all
Select 3,40
) sci on sci.student_id !=student.student_id    
Where sci.score = maths.score
```